# Node.js | callback is not defined

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm new to Node.js and I'm trying to understand callback. I was wondering what's wrong with my code. I was expecting that it will display all files without their extensions in the directory but all I got is `undefined` message.

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const postsDirectory = './app/posts';

function listPosts(callback) {
    let posts = [];
    fs.readdir(postsDirectory, function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            files.forEach(file => {
                posts.push(file.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.'));
            });
            callback(posts);
        };
    });
};

console.log(listPosts());
process.exit(0)
```

Expected Output:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use callback in following way

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const postsDirectory = './app/posts';

function listPosts(callback) {
    let posts = [];
    fs.readdir(postsDirectory, function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        } else {
            files.forEach(file => {
                posts.push(file.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.'));
            });
           //check before return here
           console.log("postttttttttttttttttt", posts);

           return callback(null, posts);
        };
    });
};

//Use callback function with params
listPosts(function(err,result){
       if(err){
          console.log(err)
        }else{
           console.log(result)
        }
 });
 process.exit(0)
```

Comment: I tried your code and the error is gone now but the list of files is not displayed though.

Comment: It's working fine now! I removed the `process.exit(0)`. Thanks for your help! :)